# Jhipster doesn't open file uploaded

Tags: jhipster

I have a entity with a blob field generated by JHipster. In the entity form I can upload a file and the form is submited normally.

The problem occurs when I'm in the view page or main page of the entity and try to open the file.

The Browser opens this tab

[image]

and prints the following message on the console.

> Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not
>   explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

There is missing some configuration in the Spring Security?

Comment: It should be done in SecurityConfiguration.java, I think it's a bug and you should report it on github.

Comment: [Ok](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10227) @GaëlMarziou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using jHipster 6.2.0.

I had the same issue and confirm this is coming from SecurityConfiguration.java (src/main/java/*your_main_package*/config folder).

Waiting for an official correction, here are the lines I commented in **configure** method to have bug solved:

```
.contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:")
    .and()
        .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
    .and()
        .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
    .and()
```

Comment: It's a bit extreme, see the fix which should be in next release https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/10230

Comment: For information, just make a test from my side. It is not working properly when adding "frame-src 'self' data:;". Not the same behavior but content is still not displayed. Precision: I have to display PDF files (and I know jhipster is focusing on pictures and not document like PDF). Maybe it is ok with pictures.